# Opencart default filter in search result

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

The Opencart's default filter is cool but it can only apply in category only. How can I make it work also in search result page?

Default filter: http://docs.opencart.com/display/opencart/Filters

Comment: Be specific.  This is too vague... Search and category display both have many thing in common.  What *specifically* does category have that search does not?

Comment: The default filter module of Opencart. http://docs.opencart.com/display/opencart/Filters

Answer (score 2):

Filter is a module and You can enable any module on any page (controller). If You haven't yet created a *Layout* for search page, simply go to `Administration -> System -> Design -> Layouts` and click on create new layout. Here enter name *Search* and `route` will be `product/search`.

Now go to `Administration -> Extensions -> Modules`, click edit on *Filters* and add new module for layout `Search`. Voilà, should be working.

Comment: Nice answer.  Taught me something new about OpenCart's power.

Comment: This is not the answer. After creating the layout, it works in category only. In search result page, it cannot filter the result!

Comment: I answered how can You display filter module on Search page - that was the question. I haven't tried this yet and therefore I cannot be wise of implications (like it is not working as You are saying).